# Is this possible? Use JSONP to get remote URL data, then convert data to javascript collection for use with javascript code

Tags: javascript, url, workflow, jsonp

Since Javascript can't make remote URL calls, I can do the following to get around it yes?

1. Use JSONP to load a remote URL with a search query and then get back data.
2. Convert the data to a javascript collection
3. Use my normal javascript code that I've already written to work with the collection.

Does anyone see any problems with this? It should work in theory yes? Is it a normal practice or is there a better way?

Comment: If the URL returns valid JSONP, sure it's possible, it the URL returns HTML and you think JSONP is a neat scraping tool, then no, that's not possible.

Comment: JSONP can only load remote JSONP data?

Comment: As far as I know you must hit JSON data that is "padded", JSONP. Example: parseResponse({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7});
Which acts as a callback to bring the data back to be evaluated from the script that is injected into the head of your page.